# ar_pose compilation issue on ros Indigo

Tags: ros, ar-pose, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to built ar_pose i get always the same error,
also in the ar_multi.cpp.

```
CMakeFiles/ar_single.dir/src/ar_single.cpp.o: In Funktion `ar_pose::ARSinglePublisher::getTransformationCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
/home/benjamin/workspace_ck/src/ar_pose/src/ar_single.cpp:215: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ar_single.cpp:

```
...
void ARSinglePublisher::getTransformationCallback (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr & image_msg)
  {
    ARUint8 *dataPtr;
    ARMarkerInfo *marker_info;
    int marker_num;
    int i, k;

    /* Get the image from ROSTOPIC
     * NOTE: the dataPtr format is BGR because the ARToolKit library was
     * build with V4L, dataPtr format change according to the 
     * ARToolKit configure option (see config.h).*/
#if ROS_VERSION_MINIMUM(1, 9, 0)
    try
    {
      capture_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy (image_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    }

    //cvNamedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // does opencv works? - yes


    //dataPtr = (ARUint8 *) ((IplImage) capture_->image).imageData;

    dataPtr = (ARUint8 *) ((IplImage) capture_->image).imageData;  //<- line 215
...
```

Hi thank you for your reply.

You're right, i had only ar_pose in my workspace. Now my workspace looks like src/ar_tools/ar_pose, artoolkit, artools and rosdep.yaml. Wenn i try to creat ar_tools, i still get the same error. Have tried all day.

This is what i get:

> 

```
Linking CXX executable
/home/benjamin/workspace_ck/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_single
 
Linking CXX executable
/home/benjamin/workspace_ck/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_multi
CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.cpp.o:
In Funktion
ar_pose::ARMultiPublisher::getTransformationCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void>
> const> const&)': ar_multi.cpp:(.text+0x2244): Nicht
definierter Verweis
auf_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat
const&)' collect2: error: ld returned
1 exit status make[2]: *
[/home/benjamin/workspace_ck/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_multi]
Fehler 1

make[1]: *
[ar_tools/ar_pose/CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/all]
Fehler 2
 
make[1]: * Auf noch nicht beendete
Prozesse wird gewartet …

CMakeFiles/ar_single.dir/src/ar_single.cpp.o:
In Funktion
 ar_pose::ARSinglePublisher::getTransformationCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void>
> const> const&)': ar_single.cpp:(.text+0x2dac): Nicht
definierter Verweis
auf_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat
const&)' collect2: error: ld returned
1 exit status make[2]: *
[/home/benjamin/workspace_ck/devel/lib/ar_pose/ar_single]
Fehler 1
 
make[1]: *
[ar_tools/ar_pose/CMakeFiles/ar_single.dir/all]
Fehler 2

make: * [all] Fehler 2 Invoking "make
-j2 -l2" failed

"Nicht definierter Verweis auf" means
"Undefined reference to"
```

I am grateful for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207698/ar_pose-compilation-issue-on-ros-indigo/) by [Kassandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/22255/kassandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-04-27**:
I am not sure what is the error, I can compile without problems in indigo.
I would suggest you to try cleaning your workspace (removing build and dev folders) and try again.

**Comment by [Leandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/22435/leandro/) on 2015-05-15**:
I'm experiencing the same problem. Could you fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from your path (/home/benjamin/workspace_ck/src/ar_pose) I'm guessing that you only downloaded the ar_pose package and not the auxiliary ones.
try checking out the whole [ar_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_tools) metapackage.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1